# Microsoft Teams Bot not clearing chat when uninstalling

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm currently working with .NET 6 and Azure Bot Services, with botframework .NET SDK.

The current workflow is the following, when receiving `OnMembersAddedAsync` event and handling it, I'm storing the necessary conversation info in a SQL database. In which later on, I'm using this conversation reference info to create a conversation between the bot and the user, in order to send a proactive type of messages to the user.

The link between the conversation user and the user in our platform is with `UserAadObjectId` fetched from the bot.

However, a client mapped their SCIM configuration in a wrong way, installed the Bot (application) to their organization before fixing the configuration. The welcome message was sent by the bot, but the conversation info were not stored. Meaning that we can't send proactive message for this client.

We tried to un-install, re-install the application in order for the user to receive the welcome message again. But the chat history in the bot was still there. And no welcome message was received.

So the main question is:

**Is there a way of un-installing and re-installing the bot in a way that all chat histories for users are cleared?**

Comment: Unfortunately currently there does not seems to be a way of doing this. However you You can implement a custom command in your bot (e.g., “reset” or “restart”). When the user types this command, the bot can simulate the welcome message behavior. This isn’t the same as the automatic welcome message on a fresh install, but it would allow you to re-trigger the behavior manually for specific users.

Comment: Alternatively If you have some identifier for the user in your system, you can add an admin functionality to your bot where, given an identifier, it sends a message directly to the user explaining the situation and asking them to perform some action to help you link their Teams identity with their identity in your system.

Comment: @Daredevil I found about these three bot handlers: `OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync`, `OnInstallationUpdateAddAsync` and `OnInstallationUpdateRemoveAsync`

Can't any of these events help? Do these events get fired when installing/uninstalling app or when??

Comment: @Daredevil any idea about the events mentioned above?

Comment: The Teams platform does not currently support clearing chat history when a bot is uninstalled and reinstalled. The chat history is preserved for compliance and user experience reasons. OnInstallationUpdateActivityAsync: This method is triggered when there is an installation update event. This could be when a bot is installed or uninstalled from a conversation thread. OnInstallationUpdateAddAsync: This method is specifically triggered when a bot is installed. OnInstallationUpdateRemoveAsync: This method is specifically triggered when a bot is uninstalled.